# How to improve my query with good performance to split a string with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I can split a string from the table below but my query was too long. I think there could be another query to make it more professional with SQL Server.

For example: `D:\Desktop\English Club\Haloween S\S.jpg`. The result which must be the folder name before the `image file`, is as `Halowwen S`or `Screenshots`

```
CREATE TABLE path(
  pathlink nvarchar(300)
)
INSERT INTO path VALUES('D:\Desktop\English Club\Haloween S\S.jpg')
INSERT INTO path VALUES('C:\Users\Safari\Pictures\Screenshots\Rate.png')
INSERT INTO path VALUES('T:\Users\users\Documents\Emicsoft Studio\ent.gif')
```

My query:

```
SELECT RIGHT(LEFT(pathlink, CHARINDEX(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(pathlink), CHARINDEX(('\'), REVERSE(pathlink)))), pathlink)-1),
        CHARINDEX(('\'), REVERSE(LEFT(pathlink, CHARINDEX(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(pathlink), CHARINDEX(('\'), REVERSE(pathlink)))), pathlink)-1)))-1)
FROM path
```

**SQLFIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/22ecc/2**

Comment: I suspect SQLCLR will perform best.  Consider a SQLCLR scalar function that wraps System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName.

Comment: FYI, I did a quick test and Pradeep's T-SQL solution outperformed both SQLCLR and your original query.

Comment: @DanGuzman-SQLServerMVP How can you test it? Is it a big data? Any way thank you very much.

Comment: I tested performance using your sample data, replicating to 1.5 million rows by running `INSERT INTO path WITH(TABLOCKX) SELECT pathlink FROM path;` repeatedly.  On my system, your query averaged 19 seconds and Pradeep's averaged 7 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. Dono whether this a better solution to ur problem!! but i tried to reduce the usage of `String functions` then your's.

```
SELECT Reverse(LEFT(Substring(Reverse(pathlink), Charindex('\', Reverse(pathlink)) + 1, 
       Len(pathlink)), Charindex('\', Substring(Reverse(pathlink), Charindex('\', Reverse(pathlink)) + 1, Len(pathlink))) - 1))
FROM   path
```

Comment: That looks greater than my query.